# Google Maps API v3 coordinates of map after move

Tags: google-maps

i am a VB.net programmer. not familiar with jscript.

I am building a web app that will display points on a google map from a database. i save the latitude and longitude for each record and use those to load the points on the map.

i have it working but i can't figure out how to update the points once the user moves the map. Is there a way to get the top-left latitude longitude and bottom-right latitude longitude of the map after the user moved or zoomed so i know which record to load from my database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want to use `map.getBounds()` when a `bounds_changed` or `idle` event is fired. I suggest you consult the events documentation for more information on events:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events